# Creating math symbols with links (mathtools)

Tags: mathtools, links

I am trying to write a command that writes linkable mathematical symbols. In particular, I want to write something like the following but that could work with the package `mathtools`:

```latex
\newcommand{\ketbralink}[2]
  {\hyperlink{ketbra}{\lvert} #1 \hyperlink{ketbra}{\rangle\langle} #2 \hyperlink{ketbra}{\rvert}}
```

my non-link `ketbra` command using `mathtools`:

```latex
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\ketbras[2]
  {\lvert}
  {\rvert}
  {#1 \delimsize\rangle\!\delimsize\langle #2}

\newcommand{\ketbra}[2]{\ketbras*{#1}{#2}}
```

I keep getting errors like ''Missing delimiter (. inserted).'' and ''Missing \right. inserted.'' when I add the command `hyperlink` to the above `ketbras` command.

My attempt:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% non-link ketbra
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\ketbras[2]
  {\lvert}
  {\rvert}
  {#1 \delimsize\rangle\!\delimsize\langle #2}
\newcommand{\ketbra}[2]{\ketbras*{#1}{#2}}

% link ketbra without mathtools
\newcommand{\ketbralinkt}[2]
  {\hyperlink{ketbra}{\lvert} #1 \hyperlink{ketbra}{\rangle\!\langle} #2 \hyperlink{ketbra}{\rvert}}

% link ketbra with mathtools
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\ketbraslink[2]
  {\hyperlink{ketbra}{\lvert}}
  {\hyperlink{ketbra}{\rvert}}
  {#1 \hyperlink{ketbra}{\delimsize\rangle\!\delimsize\langle} #2}
\newcommand{\ketbralink}[2]{\ketbraslink*{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

notation - \hypertarget{ketbras}{$\ketbra{\cdot}{\cdot}$}

ketbra with link: $\ketbralinkt{1}{2}$

mathtools ketbra with link: $\ketbralink{2}{2}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: your question would be easier to understand if you provided an example that produces the error. If you just say " keep getting errors when I add the command hyperlink" we have to guess how you added it, and the error you got. but `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` is `\left...\right` so the delimiters need to be single characters defined by the font to be extendable. You could make the whole construct a link

Comment: I added my attempt. By making the whole construct a link, would that include the parameters? So if I use $\ketbralink{3}{4}$ would $3$ and $4$ form a link as well?

Comment: as I say, you can't do `{\hyperlink{ketbra}{\lvert}}`  but it is always better to provide an example people can run to see the issue. posting disconnected fragments makes it harder to see the issue or test answers